# flutter: webview runs fine when app installed via usb, but not when installed over google play

Tags: flutter, webview

My app uses a webview to show my terms and conditions. I make use of the "webview_flutter" package to do that. When I install my app via "flutter run --release", everything works fine and my website is perfectly loaded. When I submit my app to google play in production mode, I get an error when trying to open my webview. Any idea what could cause that error?

I double checked pretty much everything. Error occurs only when installed on my Android devices via google play, but everything works fine when installed via USB cable.

```
WebView(initialUrl: 'https://xyz.abc/terms')

Expected: Webview should load
```

```
Error instead:
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(error, Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int ja
va.lang.Integer.intValue()' on a null object reference, null)
E/flutter (31498): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:564)
E/flutter (31498): #1      MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:316)
E/flutter (31498): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (31498): #2      AndroidViewController._create (package:flutter/src/services/platform_views.dart:639)
E/flutter (31498): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (31498): #3      AndroidViewController.setSize (package:flutter/src/services/platform_views.dart:556)
E/flutter (31498): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (31498): #4      RenderAndroidView._sizePlatformView (package:flutter/src/rendering/platform_view.dart:189)
E/flutter (31498): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (31498): #5      RenderAndroidView.performResize (package:flutter/src/rendering/platform_view.dart:170)
E/flutter (31498): #6      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1604)
E/flutter (31498): #7      _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy
_box.dart:105)
E/flutter (31498): #8      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1619)
E/flutter (31498): #9      RenderFlex.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart:805)
E/flutter (31498): #10     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1619)
E/flutter (31498): #11     RenderPadding.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/shifted_box.dart:206)
E/flutter (31498): #12     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1619)
E/flutter (31498): #13     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy
_box.dart:105)
E/flutter (31498): #14     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1619)
E/flutter (31498): #15     RenderConstrainedBox.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:259)
E/flutter (31498): #16     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1619)
E/flutter (31498): #17     RenderPadding.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/shifted_box.dart:206)
E/flutter (31498): #18     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1619)
E/flutter (31498): #19     RenderStack.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/stack.dart:510)
E/flutter (31498): #20     RenderObject._layoutWithoutResize (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1496)
E/flutter (31498): #21     PipelineOwner.flushLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:765)
E/flutter (31498): #22     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&SemanticsBinding&Rendere
rBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:346)
E/flutter (31498): #23     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&SemanticsBinding&Rendere
rBinding&WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:701)
E/flutter (31498): #24     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&SemanticsBinding&Rendere
rBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:285)
E/flutter (31498): #25     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/sr
c/scheduler/binding.dart:1016)
E/flutter (31498): #26     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/sch
eduler/binding.dart:958)
E/flutter (31498): #27     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/sc
heduler/binding.dart:874)
E/flutter (31498): #28     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1124)
E/flutter (31498): #29     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021)
E/flutter (31498): #30     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:923)
E/flutter (31498): #31     _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:236)
E/flutter (31498): #32     _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:194)
```

Comment: You can try my plugin [flutter_inappwebview](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview).

Comment: where you able to solve this